# Finding out if there is a daily insert into mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table which should be getting daily input regarding Vehicle mileage Readings.

```
CREATE TABLE `table_vehicle_info` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL ,
  `reg_no` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `vehicle_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `engine_no` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT "DDDD",
  `chassis_no` varchar(50) ,
  `model` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `picture` varchar(50) ,
  `rent` double ,
  `eng_power` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `color` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rent_status` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_city` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sub_type` varchar(50)  DEFAULT NULL,
  `purchase_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `purchase_amount` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `sum_insured` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `token_tax_amount` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `token_period_from` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_placed_at` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `funded_by` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=99 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `tbl_readings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `vehicle_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `km_driven` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dt_of_reading` datetime NOT NULL,
  `dt_of_entry` datetime NOT NULL,
  `entry_user` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `vehicle_id` (`vehicle_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `tbl_readings_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`vehicle_id`) REFERENCES `table_vehicle_info` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO table_vehicle_info (id,reg_no,vehicle_type ) 
VALUES (1, "B-5484",    12  );

INSERT INTO tbl_readings VALUES (NULL,1,100,'2015-6-1',NOW(), 'user');
```

I want to generate a report showing which vehicle reading isn't entered daily.

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected result of the sample data.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f47d1/1   A daily report showing the Id of vehicle which reading hasn't been entered for the previous day

Comment: Add some code of what you have tried to do, and sample data

Comment: Updated with data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e8f9

Comment: SELECT * FROM tbl_readings WHERE

dt_of_entry <> CONCAT(DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)), ' 00:00:00') AND CONCAT(DATE(NOW()), ' 00:00:00')

Comment: Luckily Stack Overflow has an edit button

Comment: Please add additional details by using the edit link, not in the comments where they will get lost.  Also show the sample data in the question.  SQL fiddle is an external site and may change or disappear which would make this question an unreadable orphan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following query, it returns all vehicle_id from `tbl_readings` for which there is no next day entry.

```
SELECT vehicle_id 
FROM `tbl_readings` 
WHERE DATE(DATE_ADD(dt_of_entry,INTERVAL 1 DAY)) NOT IN 
    (SELECT DATE(dt_of_entry) FROM `tbl_readings`)
```

**EDIT**

Try this,

```
SELECT t1.vehicle_id 
FROM `tbl_readings` t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT vehicle_id, 
        DATE(DATE_ADD(dt_of_reading,INTERVAL -1 DAY)) as reading_date 
    FROM `tbl_readings`) t2 
ON t1.vehicle_id = t2.vehicle_id AND t1.dt_of_reading = t2.reading_date
WHERE t2.vehicle_id IS NULL
GROUP BY t1.vehicle_id
HAVING COUNT(t1.vehicle_id) > 1;
```

check the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a98982/2)

Comment: I want to check for those vehicles for which there is no entry for the previous day